# Audio recording with SmartFace.io (Android - Ios)

Tags: android, ios, audio, recording, smartface.io

I'm developing a **mobile APP to record audio, save to file and then send to a server**. I'm currently using **SmartFace.io,** cross platform application to create both Android and iOS mobile apps. Been researching but can't find the audio capabilities of such platform, the online API documentation doesn't include specifics and the media items have no detailed info.

I'm not a beginner, SmartFace looks good but can't find any info regarding what I need to do. I'm not so sure if a lot of people is using it.

**What I've done:**
- Tried using PhoneGap but couldn't make it work, a coworker with more experience on Phonegap struggled until one project worked, we discovered some libraries and versions collide
- Tried samples posted here but as some other users reported, didn't work
- Also tried the now dead Mosync but the C code provided on the now dead forum doesn't work (says platform not supported). 
- I know Appcelerator have working samples but it's my last choice
- Found working projects for Android Studio but we are still trying to avoid specific work for each platform-app-IDE-framework

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smartface App Studio offers lots of ready to use components and libraries in it.

However, for current version it is not available to record an audio samples.

For more details about the features and roadmap please check the links below;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/

http://docs.smartface.io/

http://www.smartface.io/roadmap/